# Bad receiver type error "float_nullable"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I'm trying to sort a NSMutableArray containing the following NSDictionaries:

{@"Student Name": John
@"Average Test Score": 96.56}

{@"Student Name": Mary
@"Average Test Score": 93.45}
......

The average scores are stored in NSDictionary as strings, so I'm using the following code:

```
NSArray *sortedResults = [studentResultsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
return [[obj1[@"Average Test Score"] floatValue] compare:[obj2[@"Average Test Score"] floatValue]];}];
```

But I'm receiving the error prompt:Bad receiver type 'float _Nullable'

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem, or is there other ways to sort the array?

Thank you!

Comment: Do not store numbers as strings. You really need to store them as `NSNumber` objects. It will make the comparison work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `compare:` method needs to be called on objects. You are trying to call it on a `float` value.

Change this line:

```
return [[obj1[@"Average Test Score"] floatValue] compare:[obj2[@"Average Test Score"] floatValue]];}];
```

to:

```
return [obj1[@"Average Test Score"] compare:obj2[@"Average Test Score"]];}];
```

This way you call compare on the actual `NSString` objects.

This change will fix the immediate problem but will present you with another problem. This will compare the two values as strings, not numbers.

The proper solution to that is to store the averages as actual `NSNumber` instances, not as `NSString` instances.